# How do I convert JSON with variable variable names into swift object?

Tags: ios, json, swift, macos

I am working on a project with an API which gives me a JSON Object with some data in a variable. But the name of the variable under which the data is provided changes from day to day. For example today the name will be 285 and tomorrow it‘ll be 286. How can I convert this into a Swift object? I've already written some code so here it is:

Getting data part:

```
func getData(){
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore.init(value: 0)
        
        let url = URL(string: URL_STRING)!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        
        
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (dat, res, err) in
            
            print("Anfrage gestellt")
            
            guard let data = dat else {
                print("no Data")
                return
            }
            
            guard let resp = res else {
                print("No Response ")
                return
            }
            
            if let error = err {
                print("Error: \(error)")
                return
            }
            
            

            do{
                let decodedData = try self.decoder.decode(Report.self, from: data)
                print(decodedData)

                
            } catch {
                print("Data decode failed \(error)")
            }
            
            semaphore.signal()
        }.resume()
        semaphore.wait()
        
        return
    }
```

The object in which it will be converted:

```
class Report: Codable{
    
    var keys: [String] = []
    var latest: String?
    let s: S
    
    init(keys: [String], s: S){
        self.keys = keys
        self.s = s
        latest = keys[keys.count - 1]
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case s = "286"
    }
    
}
```

The JSON Object:

```
{
  "285": {
    "AT": {
      "av": -72.1,
      "ct": 113986,
      "mn": -100.813,
      "mx": -27.115
    },
    "First_UTC": "2019-09-15T01:13:15Z",
    "HWS": {
      "av": 4.347,
      "ct": 54297,
      "mn": 0.20600000000000002,
      "mx": 21.272
    },
    "Last_UTC": "2019-09-16T01:52:49Z",
    "PRE": {
      "av": 742.003,
      "ct": 89613,
      "mn": 723.2129,
      "mx": 757.8722
    },
    "Season": "spring",
    "WD": {
      "1": {
        "compass_degrees": 22.5,
        "compass_point": "NNE",
        "compass_right": 0.382683432365,
        "compass_up": 0.923879532511,
        "ct": 1
      },
      "10": {
        "compass_degrees": 225.0,
        "compass_point": "SW",
        "compass_right": -0.707106781187,
        "compass_up": -0.707106781187,
        "ct": 6973
      },
      "11": {
        "compass_degrees": 247.5,
        "compass_point": "WSW",
        "compass_right": -0.923879532511,
        "compass_up": -0.382683432365,
        "ct": 3196
      },
      "12": {
        "compass_degrees": 270.0,
        "compass_point": "W",
        "compass_right": -1.0,
        "compass_up": -0.0,
        "ct": 3066
      },
      "3": {
        "compass_degrees": 67.5,
        "compass_point": "ENE",
        "compass_right": 0.923879532511,
        "compass_up": 0.382683432365,
        "ct": 131
      },
      "5": {
        "compass_degrees": 112.5,
        "compass_point": "ESE",
        "compass_right": 0.923879532511,
        "compass_up": -0.382683432365,
        "ct": 680
      },
      "6": {
        "compass_degrees": 135.0,
        "compass_point": "SE",
        "compass_right": 0.707106781187,
        "compass_up": -0.707106781187,
        "ct": 9405
      },
      "7": {
        "compass_degrees": 157.5,
        "compass_point": "SSE",
        "compass_right": 0.382683432365,
        "compass_up": -0.923879532511,
        "ct": 8813
      },
      "8": {
        "compass_degrees": 180.0,
        "compass_point": "S",
        "compass_right": 0.0,
        "compass_up": -1.0,
        "ct": 8231
      },
      "9": {
        "compass_degrees": 202.5,
        "compass_point": "SSW",
        "compass_right": -0.382683432365,
        "compass_up": -0.923879532511,
        "ct": 13801
      },
      "most_common": {
        "compass_degrees": 202.5,
        "compass_point": "SSW",
        "compass_right": -0.382683432365,
        "compass_up": -0.923879532511,
        "ct": 13801
      }
    }
  },
    "sol_keys": [
    "285"
  ]
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Show the JSON. And do not use semaphores.

Comment: In that case you use `Dictionary`

Comment: @user28434 how do you mean? Creating a dictionary with "286" as a key and "s" as Data? I guess that will not fix my Problem because is still need to hard code the "286" in :/

Comment: What? How do you "hard code key into `Dictionary`? You just parse your `JSON` as `[String: <SomeDataType>]`

Comment: It looks like "sol_keys" contains the key(s) to use

Comment: I think in this case it will be easier to drop `Codable` and use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON).

Comment: @User28438 that seems to be the solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned you can decode this as a dictionary, first define a struct for the data you want to decode

```
struct ReportData: Decodable {
    let at: SomeData
    let firstUTC: Date
    let hws: SomeData
    //...
}
```

and then decode it as

```
let decodedData = try self.decoder.decode([String:ReportData].self, from: data)
```

to find the right key in the dictionary it looks like you can use sol_keys

```
if let keys = decodedData ["sol_keys"] {
    for key in keys {
        let report = decodeData[key]
        //...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! You are a hero!