# How to parse weather data from NASA API

Tags: json, swift, parsing

So, the issue is - I am trying to display the Mars weather from the Mars Insight API. Here is a link [Insight Weather](https://api.nasa.gov/insight_weather/?api_key=DEMO_KEY&feedtype=json&ver=1.0), the data is returning in JSON format and has three levels. The keys have names that change depending on the current date (sols). How to make the structure of mutable properties?... when the property names change every day. Do we have any instruments to parse such JSON?

```
{
  "815": {
    "First_UTC": "2021-03-12T14:54:38Z", 
    "Last_UTC": "2021-03-13T15:34:09Z", 
    "Month_ordinal": 12, 
    "Northern_season": "late winter", 
    "PRE": {
      "av": 728.378, 
      "ct": 153082, 
      "mn": 708.4211, 
      "mx": 744.9279
    }, 
    "Season": "winter", 
    "Southern_season": "late summer", 
    "WD": {
      "most_common": null
    }
  }, 
  "818": {
    "First_UTC": "2021-03-15T20:01:49Z", 
    "Last_UTC": "2021-03-16T17:32:54Z", 
    "Month_ordinal": 12, 
    "Northern_season": "late winter", 
    "PRE": {
      "av": 727.696, 
      "ct": 109855, 
      "mn": 710.223, 
      "mx": 743.946
    }, 
    "Season": "winter", 
    "Southern_season": "late summer", 
    "WD": {
      "most_common": null
    }
  }, 
"819": {
   ....

, 
  "sol_keys": [
    "815", 
    "818", 
    "819", 
    "820", 
    "821"
  ], 
  "validity_checks": {
    "815": {
      "PRE": {
        "sol_hours_with_data": [
          0, 
          1, 
          2, 
          3, 
          4, 
          5, 
          6, 
          7, 
          8, 
          9, 
          10, 
          11, 
          12, 
          13, 
          14, 
          15, 
          16, 
          17, 
          18, 
          19, 
          20, 
          21, 
          22, 
          23
        ], 
        "valid": true
      }
    }
```

So, Structure:

```
import Foundation

struct WeatherData: Decodable {
    let season: String?
    let pre: pre?
    let solKeys: [String]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case season = "season"
      case pre = "PRE"
      case solKeys = "sol_keys"
    }
    
    struct pre: Decodable {
        let av: Double?
        let mn: Double?
        let mx: Double?
        
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
          case av = "av"
          case mn = "mn"
          case mx = "mx"
        }
    }
}
```

Parsing:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let urlString = "https://api.nasa.gov/insight_weather/?api_key=DEMO_KEY&feedtype=json&ver=1.0"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return}
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let safeData = data else { return }
            do {
                let solWeather = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:WeatherData].self, from: safeData)
                if let keys = solWeather["sol_keys"] {
                    for key in keys { //error: For-in loop requires 'WeatherData' to conform to 'Sequence'
                        let report = solWeather [key]
                    }
                }
                print(solWeather)
            }
            catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
}
```

Got an error: For-in loop requires 'WeatherData' to conform to 'Sequence'
Don't understand why :(( Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: I've edited your question with sample data. Looks like the `sol_keys` array gives you a list of keys (properties) to iterate through.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57993537/how-do-i-convert-json-with-variable-variable-names-into-swift-object

Comment: @vadian Thank u! But still don't understand how to iterate through a list of keys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot decode `[String:WeatherData].self` because the dictionary contains other values which are not `WeatherData`, for example the `[String]` value of `sol_keys`.

The only way to decode this JSON with `JSONDecoder` is to implement `init(with decoder`, decode the `sol_keys` and create your own temporary `CodingKeys` to be able to decode the arbitrary dictionary keys.

First declare the custom `CodingKey`

```
public struct SolKeys: CodingKey {
   public let stringValue: String
   public init?(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }
   public var intValue: Int? { return nil }
   public init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }
}
```

The Decodable structs are

```
struct SolData : Decodable {
    let firstUTC, lastUTC : Date
    let pre : Pre
    
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case firstUTC  = "First_UTC", lastUTC  = "Last_UTC", pre = "PRE"
    }
}

struct Pre: Decodable {
    let av, mn, mx : Double
}

struct WeatherData: Decodable {
    let solKeys: [String]
    var soldata = [String:SolData]()
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case solKeys = "sol_keys"
    }
    
    init(from decoder : Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.solKeys = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .solKeys)
        let customContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: SolKeys.self)
        for key in solKeys {
            let solKey = SolKeys(stringValue: key)!
            let data = try customContainer.decode(SolData.self, forKey: solKey)
            soldata[key] = data
        }
    }
}
```

And the code to receive and decode the data

```
let urlString = "https://api.nasa.gov/insight_weather/?api_key=DEMO_KEY&feedtype=json&ver=1.0"
let url = URL(string: urlString)!

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    if let error = error { print(error); return }
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
        let solWeather = try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: data!)
        let keys = solWeather.solKeys
        for key in keys {
            let report = solWeather.soldata[key]!
            print(report)
        }
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}.resume()
```

Comment: It works perfectly! I am very grateful to you for your help! I feel like the dumbest person in the world. I still have a lot to learn, I will try very hard. Thank you again! You are a Swift-God!